# Does GetSqlValues get hidden fields?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server

I want to know how many columns a query returned in order to create an array of that size for reading the result.

Using an `SqlDataReader` I want to do something like:

```
object[] array = new object[rdr.FieldCount];
rdr.GetSqlValues(array);
```

but I'm not sure if I should use `FieldCount` or `VisibleFieldCount`. (I'm not even sure what a hidden field *is*. But I'll leave that for now.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the decompiled code from GetSqlValues()

```
public virtual int GetSqlValues(object[] values)
{
    SqlStatistics statistics = null;
    int num3;
    try
    {
        statistics = SqlStatistics.StartTimer(this.Statistics);
        this.CheckDataIsReady();
        if (values == null)
        {
            throw ADP.ArgumentNull("values");
        }
        this.SetTimeout(this._defaultTimeoutMilliseconds);
        int num2 = (values.Length < this._metaData.visibleColumns) ? values.Length : this._metaData.visibleColumns;
        for (int i = 0; i < num2; i++)
        {
            values[this._metaData.indexMap[i]] = this.GetSqlValueInternal(i);
        }
        num3 = num2;
    }
    finally
    {
        SqlStatistics.StopTimer(statistics);
    }
    return num3;
}
```

As you can see the array is checked against the visibleColumns internal value. This is the same value returned by VisibleFieldCount.

As you can see the code checks the length of the passed array and copy a number of columns that could fit in the passed array.  Because ([as from docs on VisibleFieldCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.visiblefieldcount.aspx)) the hidden fields are appended at the end of the internal array if you pass an array of FieldCount element, you will retrieve just the visible fields.